# Resort values in a pandas df

Tags: python, pandas, sorting, dataframe

I am trying to re-assign or resort values in a `pandas df` `column`.

For the code below I'm looking to reassign the `[Person]` column. Specifically, if any `Person` has less than `3 unique values` I want to combine them. If a `Person` has `3 unique values` then leave as is.

Example:

```
Person 1, A
Person 1, B
Person 2, C
Person 1, D
Person 2, E
Person 3, F
```

Using the example above, `Person 1` would be left alone as they have `3 unique values`, while `Person 3` would be grouped with `Person 2` as they have 2 and 1 respectively.

Below is what I have thus far:

```
d = ({
    'Time' : ['8:03:00','8:17:00','8:20:00','10:15:00','10:15:00','11:48:00','12:00:00','12:10:00'],                 
   'Place' : ['House 1','House 2','House 1','House 3','House 4','House 5','House 1','House 1'],                 
    'Area' : ['X','X','Y','X','X','X','X','X'],    
    'Person' : ['Person 1','Person 1','Person 2','Person 1','Person 3','Person 3','Person 1','Person 1'],                               
 })    

df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)

n = 3
df['complete'] = df.Person.apply(lambda x: 1 if df.Person.tolist().count(x) == n else 0)
df['num'] = df.Person.str.replace('Person ','')
df.sort_values(by=['num','complete'],ascending=True,inplace=True) 

c = 0
person_numbers = []
for x in range(0,999): 
    if x % n == 0:
        c += 1        
    person_numbers.append(c) 

df['Person_new'] = person_numbers[0:len(df)] 
df.Person = 'Person ' + df.Person_new.astype(str) 
df.drop(['complete','Person_new','num'],axis=1,inplace=True)

df['Time'] = pd.to_timedelta(df['Time'])
df = df.sort_values(by='Time')
```

Output:

```
      Time    Place Area    Person
0 08:03:00  House 1    X  Person 1
1 08:17:00  House 2    X  Person 1
2 08:20:00  House 1    Y  Person 2
3 10:15:00  House 3    X  Person 1
4 10:15:00  House 4    X  Person 3
5 11:48:00  House 5    X  Person 3
6 12:00:00  House 1    X  Person 2
7 12:10:00  House 1    X  Person 2
```

This isn't recognising `duplicate` `rows` in `Index 6-7`. They are the same as `Index 0`. So, `Person 1` should be assigned here. The code doesn't recognised `duplicate` `values`. If I remove these `duplicated` `rows` the code works but my actual dataset contains numerous `duplicates` can be achieved the intended out would be:

Intended Output:

```
       Time    Place Area    Person
0   8:03:00  House 1    X  Person 1
1   8:17:00  House 2    X  Person 1
2   8:20:00  House 1    Y  Person 2
3  10:15:00  House 3    X  Person 1
4  10:15:00  House 4    X  Person 2
5  11:48:00  House 5    X  Person 2
6  12:00:00  House 1    X  Person 1
7  12:10:00  House 1    X  Person 1
```

Comment: Could you explain this a little more "Specifically, if any Person has less than 3 unique values I want to combine them. If a Person has 3 unique values then leave as is."?

Comment: @cosmic_inquiry, an example has been provided. Does this make sense?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try grouping the data then iterating over the groups with whatever conditions you want.

```
d = ({
    'Time' : ['8:03:00','8:17:00','8:20:00','10:15:00','10:15:00','11:48:00','12:00:00','12:10:00'],
   'Place' : ['House 1','House 2','House 1','House 3','House 4','House 5','House 1','House 1'],
    'Area' : ['X','X','Y','X','X','X','X','X'],
    'Person' : ['Person 1','Person 1','Person 2','Person 1','Person 3','Person 3','Person 1','Person 1'],
 })

df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)

grouper = df.groupby(['Person','Area','Place'])

new_df = pd.DataFrame()

for index, group in grouper:
    # do what you want to group here
    if len(group.index) >= 2:
        # reassign to person 1?
        group['Person'] = 'Person 1'
    # append to new_df
    new_df = new_df.append(group)
```